# Highlighting python code blocks in vim

Tags: python, vim, syntax-highlighting

I wanted to highlight different indentation levels in vim, so I could identify large blocks of code more easily. I have some reasonable large nested for/while/with/try blocks and it gets hard to identify the block a am into, i.e. how many 'tabs' I have before the cursor.

Is there a way to highlight tabs?

This is what I have in mind:

```
try:
*   while True:
*   *   for foo in bar:
*   *   *   do()
*   if something:
*   *   done()
except bla:
*   exit()
```

Where * would be a special background color.

I would also settle for any other way to identify the indentation levels.

Comment: Mandatory snarky comment: perhaps you could try fixing your code instead of your editor. ;-)  +1 though for an interesting question.  I'm curious to see what this would actually look like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Indent Guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides) vim plug-in does exactly this kind of highlighting. I use it together with the `listchars` option (as Ackar pointed out).

Comment: Oh wow, that plugin is pretty cool.  It's way less obtrusive than I expected.

Comment: @Kristo I too use it and like it, unfortunately, it fails for blank likes since vim is incapable of highlighting blanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `listchars` options to display specifics characters (see `:help listchars`).

For example if you want to show tabs you could use :

```
:set listchars=tab:*\     " Be careful : there is a space after the backslash
:set list
```

You can also change the highlighting colors using the `highlight` property for the `SpecialKey` group.

If you use vim in a terminal :

```
:highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=Cyan
```

See `:help highlight` for more informations.

You can also check `:runtime syntax/colortest.vim` to see all the available colors.

Comment: Maybe you should also mention how one can set the highlighting color for listchars.

Comment: Although this does *exactly* what I asked for, it does not work for me. I used the 'expandtab' option, so there are no 'tab' chars in my scripts, only spaces. I did not know about list[chars], great tip.